# Way of knowing who called a singleton - objective C

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I am designing a game with several levels. I have a CCLayer defined as a singleton (called MasterScene) where I handle the pause page, transition page, player's score banner,... all the things common to all levels.
So in each level, when the user pushes the pause button, a call is made to the singleton to display the CClayer corresponding to the pause page. My problem is that I want to know who called the singleton (which level) t. Is there a way of doing that ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your application's architecture, I'd suggest three possible approaches:

1. Pass the level number (or pointer to the level object, or whatever) as a parameter to the singleton's methods.
2. Have the object keep track of which level is the current one, so that it already knows. (Obviously, this assumes that only the current level can be calling these methods. But I'm not sure why multiple levels would have available pause buttons.)
3. Don't make this object a singleton at all. Create an instance for each level. Is there really application-global state that this object needs to track? If you're using the MasterScene to encapsulate the behavior, but not global state, then have multiple instances of that class around doesn't really hurt anything (or consume much in devices resources).

Comment: Passing the level number as a parameter is probably the best option (and so obvious, I should have thought outside the box). I prefer the singleton method rather than adding the Pause Page as a child because the pause page has to set variables on the current level. I just don't like when children tell the parents what to do... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general way to locate the source of a message the way you are asking for.

There are however alternative architectures for your app which might solve this problem and I encourage you to consider them. What you're describing sounds like a mess of interdependent classes. All of your levels are aware of and use this MasterScene singleton and now you're trying to make the singleton aware of every level as well? Every piece of your applications shouldn't need to be aware of every other.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in as an argument, e.g.

```
@implementation Level30
-(void) pause;
{
    [[MasterScene getSingleton] pauseWithLevel:self];
}
@end
```